# event handler and datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, wpfdatagrid

I have a little problem with handling `SelectionChanged` event in a datagrid control. I would like to display simply a message when the user selects another row. The displayed message box is ok, things work fine but the selection is slowed because I call the event like this

```
private void dgemp_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show(((Emplooyee)dgemp.SelectedItem).fullname);
}
```

That is, only when I close the message box will I see the selection highlight appear on the datagrid.
Is there a method or another event I can use or call to make it select the row at once ?

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
private void dgemp_RowHeaderMouseClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show(((Emplooyee)dgemp.SelectedItem).fullname);
}
```

Comment: Thank you but what a pity C#'s WPF doesn't support RowHeaderMouseClick

Answer (score 0):

The MessagebBox is modal and will pause execution while it is open. My suggestion is to create a separate window to display your message in, display your message in a separate control in the window with your DataGrid or you could try using `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke` to create your MessageBox asynchronously.